# Calculation of the Jacobi triple product near 1

Tags: laurent-series

Anybody knows how to compute the Jacobi triple product accurately as $x \rightarrow 1$:

$$
\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{2m})(1 + x^{2m-1}y^{-2})(1 + x^{2m-1}y^{2}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^2}y^{-2n}
$$

From the right hand series there is a singularity for $x=1$. Is there any series that isolates the singularity there and is accurate with a few terms ?

Comment: I'm basically looking for accuracy but it'd also be fascinating if there is a series that isolates the behavior near 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression
$$ \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}
(1\!-\!x^{2m})(1\!+\!x^{2m-1}y^{-2})
(1\!+\!x^{2m-1}y^{2})\!=\!\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^2}y^{-2n}$$
is a Jacobi theta function according to
[DLMF equation 20.5.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.5.E3) which is equal to
$\,\theta_3(z,q)\,$ where $\,x = q\,$ and
$\, y = \exp(i\,z).\,$
Your question about $\,q\to 1\,$ is addressed in
[DLMF equation 20.7.32](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7.E32)
which is
$$ (\tau/i)^{1/2} \theta_3(z|\tau) =
\exp(i\,\tau'z^2/\pi)\, \theta_3(z\,\tau'|\tau')  $$ where $\,q = e^{\pi i \tau}\,$ since as $\,\tau\to 0\,$
we have $\,\tau'\to i\infty\,$ or $\,q'\to 0.$

Comment: That is really cool, thank you !